# Screen recording of specific views in Android

Tags: android, screen-recording

I need to record certain views in an android application, both `audio` and `video`. Say, I have a layout inside `.xml` file and I want to create a `video(.mp4)` of only that view. Whats the best approach or possible solution? So far, my finding is:

1. [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) only records the whole screen which is NOT my requirement.
2. [Javacv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) - Since the size of JAR file is way too large and I am already at the edge of meeting the `apk` size limit(100mb), plus I am already using [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) and [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) and facing `UnsatisfiedLinkingError` with Javacv. (I don't want to go for this unless there is no other option left.)

One possible solution that comes to my mind is to grab frames(bitmaps) of that view and combine them with audio to create a video file.

**Question:**
Is this possible with [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) to use the frames and audio to create a video file? How can I pass the frames to `MediaRecorder`. All I could find about `MediaRecorder` is how to stream Camera frames on [TextureView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html).

Comment: Use the media projection APIs, then crop the result.

Comment: @CommonsWare I cannot crop the results since the views are overlapping.

Comment: Then I fail to see how you could create a video by any means, since the views are overlapping. Whatever problem you have with cropping the media projection seems like that it would impact you with any of your other proposed solutions (none of which will work AFAIK).

Comment: you can create a bitmap from view and use it on opencv

Comment: @Shahzeb, did you find solution for this. i also have to record same thing.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal I used MediaProjection API and used hacks to meet my requirements like hiding some views etc.

Comment: You can use [EZ filter][1] .you can record paricular layout and export as video.