# How do I screed-record a specific view into a video?

Tags: android, android-canvas, lottie

I am using [Lottie Animation Library](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) and I want to record that animation view as video but this library does not have any video exporting support so I am trying to find my own solution and,

This is what I have tried so far.

```
    animationView.addAnimatorUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

            if((animationView.getFrame()) != previous ){
                // getting single frame
                previous = animationView.getFrame();
                FrameLayout view = frameLayout;
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                view.draw(canvas);
                bitmaps.add(bitmap);
            }

        }
    });
```

So above code `addAnimatorUpdateListener` runs every time when the animation is being updated so this function store all the bitmaps in the array.

```
for(Bitmap bitmap:bitmaps){
                    OutputStream stream;
                    try {
                        counter++;
                        stream = new FileOutputStream(imageFolder.getAbsolutePath()+"/test-"+counter+".png");
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
                        Log.i(tag, "onAnimationEnd: " + "converting... " + String.valueOf(counter) + "of " + String.valueOf(animationView.getMaxFrame()));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.i(tag, "onAnimationEnd: " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                }
```

When the animation ends Than above code convert all the images from the bitmaps array and stores them in the temporary folder. and then I am using [FFmpeg-Android](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android) to convert the video from the images in mp4.

FFmpeg command

```
String[] fcommand = new String[]{"-i", path + "test-%1d.png", "-c:v", "libx264", "-vf", "fps=30", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", path + String.valueOf(new Date()) +".mp4"};
```

From this command, I am generating video at 30 FPS.

**Issues that I am facing right now**

- Video is not so smooth even at 30 fps (420p).
- `(Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());` 30 times in one second? is it possible?

**TL;DR**

I just want to capture the bitmaps of a specific view at 30 fps how I can achieve this?

Comment: I have been on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46497611/295004) Question thread, And I am able to generate a video but still, it's laggy so I am looking for that solution but thanks anyway.

Comment: Just record the screen with a screenrecorder